# Best practice for integrating a silverlight control in a Asp.Net Solution

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, project-management, integration

I need some advice regarding the handling of a Silverlight control that I need to integrate into an existing Website, coded with Asp.Net.

I'm using SVN, Visual Studio 2010, Framework 4.0. I need to create a simple silverlight control and I need to have it embedded in one of my asp.net pages.

My question is basically, what is the best practice on where to put this Silverlight control?

1) Creating a new project for my Silverlight control and then refer to it through an external tools within my website? (importing only the .xap?)

+ Reuse
- Seems lot of extra work for a small control

2) Create a new project withing my website solution, compile it next to my website and create a post build event to copy the .xap generated into a ClientBin folders in my website?

- Lack of reusability
+ Easy to make small modifications in my Silverlight component.

3) Another solution I don't know yet??

Thanks for your advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not worry about number of projects. Reuse is far more important (we have solutions with over 100 projects).

Create a new Silverlight application, then add a Silverlight relationship between the website and your new Silverlight application:

- Right-click on your website project and select `Properties`.
- Choose the `Silverlight Applications` tab on the left side
- Press `Add...`
- Leave `Use an existing Silverlight project in the solution` checked and select the project you want to add from the `Project` dropdown.
- Leave `Add a test page that references the control` checked if you want a separate test page for your application.
- Press `Add` and you are done.

The website will now build your Silverlight application and include the output Xap file in its ClientBin folder.

[image: Add Silverlight Application dialog]

If you check "add a test page", that will give you sample HTML/ASPX pages and the JavaScript you need to run the Silverlight component anywhere in your ASP.Net app.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response ! That's exactly what I've done and I'm facing some troubles. If I do like you said, my xap is copied into the ClientBin but cannot be viewed in the page. When I generate it in another solution and manually copy-paste the xap file into the ClientBin, it works... It's driving me mad, any idea what I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: @Andy M: Once on the website a XAP file is just like any other download. Use Fiddler 2 to check that it is actually downloaded. If so assume you may be missing part of the Javascript that fires up Silverlight. Can you provide your page HTML? Also, do the Silverlight test pages it added work if you browse those instead?