# How to access client side scanner from server and upload scanned image to server?

Tags: asp.net

I have to create a web application in asp.net, that will be hosted on server and access client side scanner. The end users scan the images and scanned image is then uploaded to server. My web application is running successfully in single system. But when i hosted it in IIS and tried to access it from a client machine with a scanner attached to it, the application is not working.It is not able to access client side scanner.I am using WIA concept for scanning.

Can any one suggest a way to access client side scanner from server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly its not possible, as its a security breach.

You can use piad third party library 
like http://www.dynamsoft.com/blog/document-imaging/web-twain-webcam/how-to-scan-documents-from-an-asp-net-web-application/

http://twainx.sourceforge.net/

http://www.dosadi.com/eztwain3.htm

Or 
Flash

Or Silverlight

I would preffer a **user a control created in Silverlight for scanning purpose**. This is your WIA concept. a gud place to start.

http://10rem.net/blog/2010/04/14/scanning-an-image-from-silverlight-4-using-wia-automation

This can also be achieved by using WCF, refer

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/493333/Client-Side-Printing-Scanning-in-NET

Another way is write an Active-x control, but this solution will be limited to IEs.

Comment: i cannot use paid ddl. Is it possible to integrate silverlight with web application in server? I tried out silverlight and i found it as working. Is it possible to access client scanner using silverlight?

Comment: Yes, refer http://10rem.net/blog/2010/04/14/scanning-an-image-from-silverlight-4-using-wia-automation

Comment: I am not able to do it by silverlight. It is also running locally. But could not host in IIS. I got stuck here.

Comment: Need to more detail on "Could not host in IIS". Where have you stuck, what exception/error are you getting? These can be related to permission most probably then you need to gave elevated permissions. Please share specific details.

Comment: I had created the silverlight application. It scans well locally.But i dont know how to integrate it with web application. Whether this silverlight application is to be implemented in client or server? Any reference links?Please specify how it breaks security breach and access client scanner.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nipuntomar/using-silverlight-controls-in-Asp-Net/    and  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838145(v=vs.95)   and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093540/best-practice-for-integrating-a-silverlight-control-in-a-asp-net-solution and  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18406/Sample-Application-to-Integrate-Silverlight-and-AS

Comment: I am getting following error while running silverlight.
"System.notSupportedException:This operation is not supported in current context." at line
 dynamic wiaDialog = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WIA.CommonDialog");
I am getting result locally in out of browser mode. But i need In-Browser mode. Please Help..

Comment: I had used ActiveX and is working fine now. Thanks for your reply.